# Access bash positional parameter through variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How to access bash positional parameter through a variable?
e.g. I have a variable "pos", which can be anything between 1 to 6 (say).

If `pos==1`, I want to do: `echo $1`

If `pos==2`, I want to do: `echo $2`

So on.

Intuitively, I want to do something like: `echo $$pos`.
I want to do it in one line.

Answer (score 4):

Use variable indirection:

```
echo "${!pos}"
```

Comment: @tanmoy: Are you running `bash`?

Comment: @tanmoy: What version? Did you set `$pos` and the positional parameters?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash ; pos=1 ; echo "${!pos}"`

Comment: @tanmoy: Works for me. What bash version do you run?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @tanmoy: It should be OK. When I replace ; with newlines, it works.

Comment: You are right. I found out that my hashbang was actually being ignored when I was running it by `sh scriptname`. Now I have fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several solutions. Some may need a recent version of `bash`, others may still work with a very old one.

Let us set up first our environment...

```
$ set first second third fourth
$ pos=3
```

#### Substring  expansion

```
$ printf 'Parameter %d is "%s"\n' "$pos" "${@:pos:1}"
Parameter 3 is "third"
```

This is very flexible:

- Can match several consecutive parameters: `"${@:pos:2}"`
- Can match all the remaining parameters starting from `pos`: `"${@:pos}"`
- Works with literals, variable `pos` is not necessary: `"${@:3:2}"`
- Works also with any arithmetic expression: `"${@:(pos-1)*2:1}"`
- Works also with negative numbers (counts down from the last):

```
$ printf 'Last parameter is "%s"\n' "${@: -1}"    # Mind the space!
Last parameter is "fourth"
$ printf 'Parameter %d is "%s" to last\n' "$pos" "${@: -pos:1}"
Parameter 3 is "second" to last
```

#### Intermediary array

Bash's arrays are very flexible. Just put your script parameters into an array and access its elements with `pos`:

```
$ args=( "$0" "$@" )
$ printf 'Parameter %d is "%s"\n' "$pos" "${args[pos]}"
```

Advantages:

- Straightforward array notation `array[pos]`
- Array index may be negative (counting down from the last element)
- Array index may be any arithmetic expression: `"${args[(pos-1)*2]}"`
- Can be combined with substring expansion, so all its advantages apply here too: `"${args[@]:pos:2}"`

#### Indirect expansion

The `${!var}` syntax fetches the content of `var` and the whole is substituted with `$content`. If `var` contains a number n, the whole is substituted with the nth positional parameter.

```
$ printf 'Parameter %d is "%s"\n' "$pos" "${!pos}"
Parameter 3 is "third"
```

Drawbacks:

- Less flexible than above solutions

#### eval

Father of all evils, `eval` may still be useful if you shell doesn't support any of the above:

```
$ eval "param=\${$pos}"     # Just eval the assignment, nothing more
$ printf 'Parameter %d is "%s"\n' "$pos" "$param"
Parameter 3 is "third"
```

Advantages:

- Works in any Bourne shell
- Flexibility: with `eval` you can do anything (and this is also the problem with it)

Drawbacks:

- `eval` is a beast that is difficult to tame. Limit its use to the strict minimum. For example, only `eval` the assignment given above in example and nothing more (this necessitates the temporary variable `param`). Of course, sanity check of `pos` is mandatory but this is also the case for the other commands given here.

#### Subshell

Since subshells inherit the positional parameters, and since what happens in subshells stays in subshells, we can use these properties to shift the parameters:

```
$ printf 'Parameter %d is "%s"\n' "$pos" "$(shift $((pos-1)); printf %s "$1")"
Parameter 3 is "third"
$ echo "$1"   # Check that parameters weren't shifted in parent shell
first
```

Advantages:

- Works in any Bourne shell
- Arithmetic operations on `pos`