# How to access "variable position" command line argument in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to access the argument at position 'pos'. [Here pos is variable from 1 to numOfArguments]

```
myNumber=$1
```

It will store the first cmd line element

```
myNumber=$2
```

It will store the second cmd line element

```
pos=3

myNumber=$pos
```

It is not storing 3rd cmd line argument.
Instead, it is storing integer 3 to myNumber variable

Comment: You need an indirect variable reference: `myNumber=${!pos}`

Comment: Noooo. That's not what I want

Comment: @stackaayush: Maybe this is a [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? If you just want to process a variable number of arguments in sequence, it is often easier to parse them from left to right and use `shift` to get rid of the argument which is already processed, so that the next unprocessed element is always `$1`.

Comment: @stackaayush : What Gordon Davisson suggested, exactly answers what you have asked. If you want to know something different, you have to ask in a different way.

Comment: I understand OP's "nooo" reaction. This is closed as a duplicate of a question about "indirect variable referencing". This is far from the best "closed as a duplicate" I have seen. First of all, the other question doesn't deal at all with parameters and this is up to the OP to figure out how to adapt the answers there. Moreover, there is more than one way to do what the OP asks, and the other question does not lead to optimal code when the parameter position is not stored in a variable, e.g. "last" or "second to last". If not closed, this could have been an interesting question.

Comment: @stackaayush Here is a more direct answer to your need: [Access bash positional parameter through variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29015943/7233423)

Comment: @xhienne Yeah that's what I wanted : )

Comment: @stackaayush I have added my answer there since this question is now closed, you may find it interesting